# HTML table to xlsx spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel, google-chrome-extension, download

I'm building a chrome extension and I need to download a table created dinamically with xlsx extension. This is the relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab">
<table class="sortable" id="mytab">
<tr class="visible">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr id="t0">
  <td id="d0"></td>
  <td id="p0"></td>
</tr>
<!--Here are 299 other rows-->
<tr id="t300">
  <td id="d300"></td>
  <td id="p300"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The table contains 300 rows with numerical IDs and in the .css file I set the display:none for every cell.
I use a for loop to dinamically add content and make the cells visible if not empty. This is the js that fills the table checking the arrays *names* and *ages*:

```
for(var i=0; i<301; i++){
  if ((names[i]!=undefined)&&(ages[i]!=undefined)){
      document.getElementById('t'+i).style.display="table-row";
      document.getElementById('d'+i).innerHTML=names[i];
      document.getElementById('d'+i).style.display="table-cell";
      document.getElementById('p'+i).innerHTML=ages[i];
      document.getElementById('p'+i).style.display="table-cell";

  }
  else break;
}
```

It perfectly work but I now need to make the table downloadable. If I go with rightclick+save as... and then I change the extension to .xlsx it produces the spreadsheet I want, though it saves every html tag and it's not practical to do. So I would like an easy way to just right click and save the pure valuse as xlsx table. I already created a context menu entry to do this using

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Save results", "onclick": download});
```

where *download* is the following function:

```
function download(){
  chrome.downloads.download({
  url: window.location.href,
  saveAs: true,
  filename: "Table.xlsx"
  });
}
```

However, doing so it only saves the table header, without values added dinamically. So I checked here on stackoverflow and on google to find a way to download the table. None of the solutions I found was helpful:

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('mytab').outerHTML));
```

This one returns a blank file without extension and many other solutions I found did the same. Also, I don't want it to download as CSV and would prefer a solution with vanilla javascript.

My question is: is there a way to download my table as xlsx with a simple click on the menu entry?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will need to write the right xlsx format manually or with a library. browsers dont know how to convert it for you.

Comment: @ZigMandel ahhh that's why I couldn't find a solution... What might be such a library? I will try it though at this point it might be easier to export it as google doc

Comment: in s.o. its offtopic to ask for library recommendations. see the guidelines.

Comment: @Dilly, use any search engine e.g. google for `javascript xlsx create library` and you'll see an answer in a couple of seconds needed to type the query text.

Comment: @wOxxOm that's what I meant, thanks... It wasn't my intention to be OT, I was just asking _how_ are those libraries named... Thanks again